# How to pre-select an option on select (Struts 2)

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I'm having problems pre-selecting a value on a  with struts 2.

I'm using the tag value="country" to target to a String country="Japan" , and the select  loads the elements from a list (string list).

But, on load the select just target the first item on the list.

look:

```
<s:select list="countries" value="country" label="Conutry" 
                                  headerKey="null" name="country" id="selectCountry"
                                  />


public List<String> countries;
public String country;
.....

public Countries(){
         countries=dao.list();
}


.........

getter and setter

........
//Action Used to get information
public getInfo(){
    country="USA"
}
```

Comment: Do you have typo in your code `contry` vs `country`?

Comment: hahha sorry my mistake writing the question!.. But is correct on muy code.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```xml
<s:select list="countries" 
          value="country" 
          label="Conutry" 
          headerKey="country" 
          headerValue="contry" 
          name="countries" 
          id="selectCountry"/>
```

`headerKey` indicates the value you are posting.
`headerValue` will be shown on the list.

Comment: thanks! , but headerkey/value are hardTyped options like "select an option" with a key "null" . So if I enter headerKey="country" and headerValue="country" I'll get a "country" as preselected option, and I want the option that is setted on the action.

Comment: @rafuru you do have `public String getInfo(){}`, you can use `headerValue="%{info}"` to return a string from action